# Unable to Inject 3rd Party Scripts in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

The following code is required to be injected into the head for Sovrn display ads:

```
<script type="application/javascript">var googletag=googletag||{};googletag.cmd=googletag.cmd||[];googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad()});</script><script type="application/javascript" src="//ap.lijit.com/www/headerauction/headersuite.min.js?configId=XXXX"></script>
```

It looks for a div with ID="21728840" to display an ad for that div. I'm using Netlify so injecting this script into the head is not an issue, but Netlify does this post-process. Therefore, by the time, the script loads, it is not able to find the ID since the element is not defined, and returns a 403 error. I looked at many suggestions, and tried to use useEffect in the file where the ad is like so:

```
export const BlogIndexTemplate = ({ posts, title...
...
useEffect(() => {
    var googletag = googletag || {}
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || []
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad()
    })
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.src =
      '//ap.lijit.com/www/headerauction/headersuite.min.js?configId=XXXX'
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }, [])
...
{!!posts.length && (
              <section className="section">
                <div className="container">
                  <PostSection posts={filteredPosts} />
                </div>
              </section>
            )}
```

The ad container is located in PostSection like so:

```
class PostSection extends React.Component {
...
<div className="sidebar-sticky-container">
                  <div className="ad-skyscraper-container sticky-widget">
                    <div id="21728840"></div>
```

I'm not sure what other approach I could try to get the script injected, and manipulate the div with ID 21728840 to display the ad.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I discovered that using useEffect and most of the suggestions online are unnecessary for Gatsby. To inject a 3rd party script, one needs to create a gatsby-ssr.js file in the root directory. Inside this file, one should have the following for a basic set up:

```
const React = require('react')

exports.onRenderBody = function({
  setHeadComponents,
  setPreBodyComponents
}) {
setHeadComponents([
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{whateveryouneedtoset}}>
])
setPreBodyComponents([
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{whateveryouneedtoset}}>
])
}
```

All options for using the gatsby-ssr.js file can be found here: [Gatsby SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/)